# How to split a row at every nth column and stack it below in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have this single column dataframe with sorted values

```
Gene Symbol
AAAS
ABCC8
ABCD4
ABL1
ACAA1
ACADM
ACADS
ACD
ACO2
ACOX1
ACP5
ACSL4
ACTB
ACTG1
ADA
ADA2
ADAM17
ADAMTS13
ADAMTS3
ADAR
ADCY1
ADCY2
ADCY3
ADCY4
ADCY5
ADCY6
ADCY7
ADCY8
ADCY9
ADIPOQ
```

and I want to rearrange this in 10 row table, like this:-
[image]

So far I have sued this below code :-

`(pd.DataFrame(newDf.groupby(newDf.index // 10)['Gene Symbol'].apply(list).values.tolist()).fillna(''))`

But it does not looks like above table:-
[image]

Comment: Numpy reshape maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this... if #rows are multiple of 10

```
np.array(df["Gene Symbol"]).reshape(10,int(df.shape[0]/10))
```

else, try this... where will first make dataframe multiple of 10 then split as required;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"Gene Symbol":range(1,36)})
lst = list(df["Gene Symbol"]) + [np.nan]*(df.shape[0]%10)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst).reshape(int(len(lst)/10),10))

# Output
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0   6.0   7.0   8.0   9.0  10.0
1  11.0  12.0  13.0  14.0  15.0  16.0  17.0  18.0  19.0  20.0
2  21.0  22.0  23.0  24.0  25.0  26.0  27.0  28.0  29.0  30.0
3  31.0  32.0  33.0  34.0  35.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: ``np.array(df["Gene Symbol"]).reshape(10,-1)``

Comment: Actually I just pasted a small part of the column, it is not in even number so its throwing an error. ```cannot reshape array of size 2369 into shape (10,5)``` like this

Comment: Try now... Here, we can add nan to avoid such errors... & split into 10-10 rows...

Comment: @SachinKohli Thank you. Your code worked. Well I had to tweak it a little bit because it didn't work with my dataset. As my dataset size changes everytime.
```lst = list(df_all["newTrial"]) + ((10 - (df_all.shape[0]%10))*[np.nan])```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a few steps using floor division and `cumcount` with `.unstack`

```
df = df.set_index(df.index // 10)

df1 = df.set_index(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),append=True).unstack(1)
```

---

```
print(df1)
  Gene Symbol
            0      1      2      3      4      5       6         7        8       9
0        AAAS  ABCC8  ABCD4   ABL1  ACAA1  ACADM   ACADS       ACD     ACO2   ACOX1
1        ACP5  ACSL4   ACTB  ACTG1    ADA   ADA2  ADAM17  ADAMTS13  ADAMTS3    ADAR
2       ADCY1  ADCY2  ADCY3  ADCY4  ADCY5  ADCY6   ADCY7     ADCY8    ADCY9  ADIPOQ
```

Comment: Hi Umar. Could I trouble you to use an English spellchecker please?

Comment: @halfer I'm really limited with what extensions I'm allowed to use at work & I'm tad of a privacy nut - I've been more mindful with recent posts. Sorry for the trouble my friend. Have a great weekend!

Comment: I hear you on the privacy angle. Nevertheless, spelling is important here, not least to help avoid giving editors new work to do! 

Comment: I acknowledge "lets" is tricky - in the context of, say, this sentence: "A lambda lets you run code in a serverless environment" there is no apostrophe. In that case, "lets" is one word, and it refers to something/someone giving permission or ability. However, for "let's try an example", the word "let's" is a _contraction_ i.e. two words merged into one. That has a slightly different meaning: "let us" i.e. a call to action to do something.

Comment: One way to remember is merely to read a sentence through and mentally swap "lets" with "let us" - if it still makes sense, then it needs an apostrophe.

Comment: Have a good weekend also!